# create dynamic tree using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code for dynamic tree view using php mysql.

```
function fetchCategoryTreeList($parent = '', $user_tree_array = '') 
{
  // code here 
}
```

i just want ...like. i have a variable

```
$top = '1234';
```

now how to put in this function like

```
function fetchCategoryTreeList($parent = $top, $user_tree_array = '') 
{
  // code here 
}
```

if i put $top in this function then i got fatal error. Please help me

Comment: Can't have a fatal error just by adding $top = '1234' ; into the function. We need your real code to see the problem.

Comment: You can't set default value as another variable.

Comment: @PierreGranger He got error because of `$parent = $top` in function argument

Comment: Oops sorry that was obvious. Op, why you want to do that ? $parent='' in function declaration is just a "default" value, most of the time you don't have to set one.

Il you really need : function foo($var,$var2) { global $top ; if ( $var == null ) $var = $top ; ... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need a default dynamic value :

```
$top = '1234' ;

// Some code

function fetchCategoryTreeList($parent = '', $user_tree_array = '') 
{
  global $top ;
  if ( $parent == null || $parent == '' ) $parent = $top ;
  // code here 
}
```

But if the value is constant take a look at B Desai answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cant assign default value as another variable to arguments. You can use constant instead

```
define("TOP", "1234");
function fetchCategoryTreeList($parent = TOP, $user_tree_array = '') 
{
  // code here 
}
```